# Re-create django migrations without migrations folder

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a bit of an issue.

I tried to re-create my sqlite db of my project. Only problem is that by uploading my project on a git, I ignore the "migrations" folder of each app so my client wouldn't be bothered by it (wrong practice?).

But today, I would like to take that db from scratch (column order, recreate full install from csv data, ...) but when i execute my migrations commands, they detect no changes and only migrate django table.

Django version : 2.0.13
Python : 3.7.3

Comment: The migrations are stored in the migrations folder. The idea is that `makemigrations` detects changes in the models (compared to the model you retrieve when you would create models with the files in the `migrations` files), and the files in the migrations can be translated to SQL queries to migrate the database.

Comment: I understand, but my issue is that I cannot detect to what ```makemigrations``` compare changes to know that there are no changes to apply although my database is empty...

Comment: of course, where would it find the difference if the repository does not contain any migrations. Normally it will not generate any trouble when you add migrations to the git repository, since Django can work with merging migrations: it can create merge migrations.

Comment: I wouldn't ignore the migrations. That sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer and easily done with a script.

```sh
# Do this following line as much as you have applications
python path_to_project\manage.py makemigrations <app_name> --empty
# After every empty migrations done, do the two following lines
python path_to_project\manage.py makemigrations
python path_to_project\manage.py migrate
```

Comment: This only creates initial migration files, you really shouldn’t be ignoring migration files in your repo in the first place

Comment: I agree @IainShelvington. This solution is to repair a mistaken easily done and be able to re-create my db, even empty.

Just done it and every migrations folders has been created with ```__init__.py``` included